# How do I stop an animation when tapped

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, uibutton

I'm making a tap game, and this is the button with the animation. It is very slow, and I want to speed it up so when the user taps, it will reset the animation and count the tap.

Currently, it is slow to the point that it will miss taps if tapped again while the animation is still going on.

```
@IBAction func slimeTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    tapCount += tapIncrease
    checkLevel(tapCount)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.03, animations: {
        //shrink
        self.playSound()
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
    }, completion: {_ in
        //change it back to how it was
        //grow
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.05, animations: {
           sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: So are you looking to speed up the animation, or stop the animation when tapped? These are two very different things.

Comment: Stop animation when tapped. This way tapping the button will register more taps since the animation will end. Currently it is processing the animation when tapping and not registering all taps

Comment: You forgot https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/uiviewanimationoptionallowuserinteraction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `.layer.removeAllAnimations()` to remove any existing animations on the layer, and `.allowUserInteraction` as an animation option to enable and register user tap events:

```swift
@IBAction func slimeTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    tapCount += tapIncrease
    checkLevel(tapCount)

    resizingView.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        self.playSound()
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
    }) { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
        })
    }
}
```